# Ios design can't scroll when autolayout is off

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, autolayout, uicontainerview

I can't make scrollable view when autolayout is disabled.

Any suggestion?

Tableview is `Ad Related Container View`, and i can't scroll on it.

But every containerview is not scrollable. (3 containerviews)

[image]

EDIT:
[image]

[image]

Container size inspector:

[image]

Containers tableview:

[image]

Comment: Check if scrolling is enabled, check the size of your tableview, if it clings to the window. It might be bigger than your screensize, thats one of the reasons it would behave like this.

Comment: Size is fixed, becouse it is embeded in container view, so it takes size of that container, scrolling is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the table view uses `estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath` to determine roughly how big the table will be. You probably need to make sure that this returns semi accurate heights for your cells, otherwise it might not show the scrollbar. You can return `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` for this if you do not know the size. If auto layout is off, not sure how this works. If it does nothing try using a value you think is sensible.

Also check what you are returning from `heightForRowAtIndexPath` in case it is too small.

Also check that scrolling is enabled.

Comment: But this is not problem only on tableview, it is problem on 3 container views, so i think that problem is with container view?

Comment: Is you container view content pinned to the bottom of the container view so it has to scroll? Hard to know what is going on without you showing more information on these container views.

Comment: What i need to show you, tell me i will screenshot?

Comment: Ideally a description of your view hierarchy and constraints and any manual code you setup constraints or views in.

Comment: I added more screenshots, but i don't have code in controller.

Comment: You have no constraints at all by the look of things. Your container views are probably just extending off the bottom of the screen as they fill up meaning no scroll is required. I would add constraints to the scroll view pinning it to the top and bottom layout guides and the sides. You then need constraints which pin the contents to each other and the scroll view top/bottom and sides. Also need layout for the 3 controller container views.

Comment: Added 2 more images with size inspector for container and container tableview, what you think now?

Comment: Apologies it is too difficult to see what is going in with this. My suggestion would be to code all this using constraints so you are explicitly saying where everything should go and how it should behave on resize etc,,,